# Uploading jpg file from Android phone to server (differs between wifi and 3g phone connection)

Tags: php, android

I am uploading a jpg file from my Android phone to a Linux server(raspberry pi) running Apache and PHP, via a php webpage. When the phone has a wifi connection it's successful, when it's via the 3G phone connection, it fails.

The server is running headless. In both cases the response is '200 Ok'

My Android code and the receiving php is shown below:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(byte[]... jpeg) {
try {
    String filename = "phoneuser.jpg";
    filename = "photocaps/" + OWNER + "_user.jpg";
    String servUrl = mServerURL;
    String uploadPHP = mServerURL + "photoupload.php";

    byte[] byteSource = convertByteArrayByRotation(jpeg);
    int startLength = byteSource.length;
    String b64encStr = Base64.encodeToString(byteSource,
                        Base64.DEFAULT);

    int convertedLength = b64encStr.length();
    final ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new    
         ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", b64encStr));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", filename));
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uploadPHP);

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                Log.e("PictureDemo", "Exception in photoCallback", e);
    }

        return (null);
    }
    }
```

On server

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/s$
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<?php
$base=$_REQUEST['image'];
$filename=$_REQUEST['fname'];
echo $base;
$binary=base64_decode($base);
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
$file = fopen($filename, 'wb');
 $fwrite = fwrite($file, $binary);
if ($fwrite === false) {
     echo "write error";  // no use in headless
}
fclose($file);
?>
</html>
```

The receiving directory is owned by www-data. I know that the HttpPost is deprecated but it works OK over wifi but not 3G and that is what I want to fix first. Is there anything I can do server side to narrow down the cause of the error? Why does it differ between a wifi and a 3G connection between phone and server. The server web pages are visible on phone via 3G.

Comment: `when it's via the 3G phone connection, it fails.`. Describe better what happens on 3G instead. Errors? Exceptions?

Comment: Please add the code where you read the page sent by php.

Comment: There are no errors to be seen, however the file does not get to the server. I can see that when I list the directory.

Comment: It seems to be dependent on file size. At 100% jpeg quality (~250Kbytes) it fails on 3G, at 50% quality set by bmp.compress (~85K), it is transmitted OK. I don't know why this, so I have a cludge of a fix but not an explanation for the fault.